# I want a alertDialogRadio box in my home activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm getting error like this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.splash.indivillage.indishare/com.splash.indivillage.indishare.Home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object referenceOnClickListener

```
listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /** Getting the fragment manager */
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        /** Instantiating the DialogFragment class */
        AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();

        /** Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index */
        Bundle b  = new Bundle();

        /** Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object */
        b.putInt("position", position);

        /** Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object */
        alert.setArguments(b);

        /** Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window */
        alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");
    }
};

/** Getting the reference of the button from the main layout */
ImageButton abuseBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.abuseImageView);

/** Setting a button click listener for the choose button */
abuseBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and add some useful descriptions. I will be easier for others to help you.